# Object method does not return result

Tags: php, html, css

I can not recover a value of a request, I have to recover a data object on a character from the database thanks to its name and then display this information.

So when I'm going to want to use my character, just enter his name so we come across this:

```php
// If want use a character
elseif(isset($_POST['use']) && isset($_POST['name']))
{
    if($manager->exist($_POST['name']))
    {
        $perso = $manager->getPerso($_POST['name']);
    }
    else
    {
        $message = 'Ce personnage n\'existe pas !';
    }
}
```

The function getPerso is cella that will return the data object from the database, this method is in the class PersonagesManager:

```php
public function getPerso($info)
{
  $column = is_int($info) ? 'id' : 'namePerso';
  $q = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT id, namePerso, damage FROM personnages WHERE ' . $column . '=:' . $column);
  $q -> bindValue(':' . $column, $info);
  $q -> execute();

  return new Personnage($q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
}
```

At the level of my class Character, nothing very complicated I get his name thanks to the method :

```php
public function name()
    { return $this->_name; }
```

Then, when I send the form, I pass on some checks, then when the character is recover with the method getPerso and so $ perso is defined, I display the page about the infos of this character to know: The number of created, His name, These damage and finally a list of characters other than him to hit:

```php
if(isset($perso))
        {
            print_r($perso);
        ?>

        <p><a href="?deconnexion=1">Déconnexion</a></p>

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Mes informations :</legend>
            <p>
                Nom : <strong><?php echo htmlspecialchars($perso->name()); ?></strong><br/>
                Dégats : <strong><?php echo $perso->damage(); ?></strong>
            </p>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Qui frapper ?</legend>
            <p>
            <?php 
            $persos = $manager->getListPerso($perso->name());

            if(empty($persos))
            {
                echo 'Personne à frapper !';
            }
            else
            {
                foreach($persos as $onePerso)
                {
                    echo "<a href='?hit=" . $onePerso->id() . "'>" . htmlspecialchars($onePerso->name()) . "</a> Dégats : (" . $onePerso->damage() . ")<br/>";
                }
            }         
            ?>
        </fieldset>

        <?php
        }
```

But I can not get the $ requete value ['namePerso'], when I get my method getPerso a fetch and I send instead of the new Personnage -> new Personnage (['namePerso' => $ request [ 'namePerso']]);

I can display the Name! But the other infos are not sent !

```php
public function getPerso($info)
    {
        $column = is_int($info) ? 'id' : 'namePerso';
        $q = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT id, namePerso, damage FROM personnages WHERE ' . $column . '=:' . $column);
        $q -> bindValue(':' . $column, $info);
        $q -> execute();

        $donnees = $q -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        return new Personnage(['name' => $donnees['namePerso']]);
    }
// Returns the name but without the other info ...
```

If not, the name is no longer displayed, unlike the id and the damage!

EDIT ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

So what i tried :

- By displaying the name directly in the class which gives me :

```
public function getPerso($info)
    {
        $column = is_int($info) ? 'id' : 'namePerso';
        $q = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT id, namePerso, damage FROM personnages WHERE ' . $column . '=:' . $column);
        $q -> bindValue(':' . $column, $info);

        $q -> execute();

        $donnees = $q -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        echo $donnees['namePerso'];
        exit();

        //return new Personnage($q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
    }
```

Result : The name is well displayed
[The name displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fqaui.jpg)

- By sending only the name to my router from the request as follows :

```
public function getPerso($info)
    {
        $column = is_int($info) ? 'id' : 'namePerso';
        $q = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT id, namePerso, damage FROM personnages WHERE ' . $column . '=:' . $column);
        $q -> bindValue(':' . $column, $info);

        $q -> execute();

        $donnees = $q -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        return new Personnage(['name' => $donnees['namePerso']]);

        //return new Personnage($q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
    }
```

Result : The name is well return, but not others infos, so when i uncomment a last line for return all infos, the name is not return ...
[The name well displayed but not others infos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMvRz.jpg)

My actual code : --------------------

```
public function getPerso($info)
    {
        $column = is_int($info) ? 'id' : 'namePerso';
        $q = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT id, namePerso, damage FROM personnages WHERE ' . $column . '=:' . $column);
        $q -> bindValue(':' . $column, $info);

        $q -> execute();

        return new Personnage($q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
    }
```

Comment: By `other infos` do you mean the `damage` and `id` are gone? If you output the `$donnees` prior to the return do you have the data?  Maybe the issue is that you are only returning the `namePerso` index?

Comment: Yes, other infos like damage and id, i have change my message for more precision with a image !

Comment: Do you mean using `return new Personnage(['name' => $donnees['namePerso']]);` gives you the name and `return new Personnage($q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))`  gives you the other data?

Comment: Yes ! But ```return new Personnage($q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))``` don't give me a name ! Only damage and id

Comment: You are calling `fetch` twice, only do that once. Although that should give all columns, just skip first row.

Comment: I did not understand quite well ? Which line are you talking about

Comment: `$donnees = $q -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` then `$q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` will fetch twice so you end up on second row.

Comment: No I wrote this to show you the test -> My initial getPerso() only return : ```return new Personnage($q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));```

Comment: Please update the question to show your actual code.

Comment: It's done well !

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for a solution :

- My request need to return array with key : 'id', 'name', 'damage' and don't 'namePerso'

So I put the namePerso field in the name variable :

```
$q = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT id, namePerso AS name, damage FROM personnages WHERE ' . $column . '=:' . $column);
```